# I have to prove that the following is true using the mean value theorem

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

If $f'(x)=\sqrt{x^3+1}$ for all $x>0$ and $f(2)=10$, then $f(5) > 16$.

I have what is below so far, but I am not sure how to show f(5) > 16.

Assume $f'(x) = \sqrt{x^{3} + 1}$ for all $x > 0$ and $f(2) = 10$.Since $f'(x)$ is differentiable for all $x > 0$ then $f$ is differentiable on $(2, 5)$ and $f$ is continuous on [$2, 5$].

Comment: Did you try the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$Hint**:

The *Mean value theorem*  asserts that
$$\frac{f(5)-f(2)}{5-2}=f'(c),\quad c\in(2,5)$$
and $f'(c)>\dots$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Applying the MVT on the interval $[2,5]$ implies the existence of some $c \in [2,5]$ such that
$$\frac{f(5)-f(2)}{5-2} = f'(c) = \sqrt{c^3 + 1}$$
i.e.
$$f(5) = f(2) + (5-2) \sqrt{c^3 + 1}.$$

Comment: It looks like we in fact have $f(5) > 19$ from this.